# Float:right div will not display inline

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-float

I have just uploaded my site to hosting and an issue is occurring that wasn't when I was viewing it just from my desktop.

The 'sidebar' class which should be floated right seems to send its self to the bottom of the page.

When I re-size the browser to test the site and check the media queries are working, then maximize the browser again, the 'about' section positions itself where it originally should have.

The issue seems to only occur in `Chrome`. (Have tested in IE and FF and both seem fine)

http://barbsbristol.co.uk/

is the site & the style sheet is

http://barbsbristol.co.uk/style.css

& the `css` of sidebar class is below

```
.sidebar 
 {
     float:right; 
     display:inline-block;  
     margin-top:50px;  
     width:150px; 
     height:100px; 
     text-align:center;
  }
```

Comment: it is working fine for me in chrome and other browser

Answer (score 0):

it is working fine to me also in chrome and other browsers.. few styles may be messed up with same browser but different versions.. I already face these kind of problems among same browser different versions..

Why don't you use Inspect Element & check by reducing width?? Since it is working fine to me I could not suggest anything else mate.